# Estimating risk differences for marginal models

Tags: performance, r

I need to estimate risk differences for marginal models. I have worked on the [Probratio function](https://rdrr.io/cran/epitools/src/R/probratio.r) to create an equivalent function for RDs that works.

Please provide feedback on accuracy or comments to improve efficiency where necessary.

```
 probdiff <- function(object, parm, subset, method=c('ML', 'delta', 'bootstrap'), scale='linear', level=0.95, seed, NREPS=1000, ...) {
  if (length(match('glm', class(object))) < 0) 
    stop('Non GLM input to "object"')
  if (family(object)$family != 'binomial')
    stop('object not a logistic regression model')
  nc <- length(cf <- coef(object))
  if (missing(subset))
    subset <- T
  if (missing(parm))
    parm <- seq(2, nc)
  cf <- cf[parm]
  
   method <- match.arg(method, c('ML', 'delta', 'bootstrap'))
   
   scale <- 'linear'
   if (is.na(scale))
     stop('scale cannot take values outside of linear')
   if (scale == 'linear') {
     f <- function(x) x[2] - x[1]
     name <- c('Risk difference')
     null <- 0
   } else{
     (is.na(scale))
     stop('scale cannot take values outside of linear')
   }
   cilevel <- c({1-level}/2, 1-{1-level}/2)
   ciname <- paste0(c('Lower', 'Upper'), ' ', formatC(100*cilevel, format='f', digits=1), '% CI')
   
   if (method == 'ML') {
    newfit <- glm(object, family=binomial(link="identity"), subset=subset, ...) 
     out <- coef(summary(newfit))[parm, , drop=F]
     if (scale == 'linear') {
         out <- cbind(out[, 1], out[, 2], out[, 3], out[, 4], out[, 1] + qnorm((1-level)/2)*out[, 2], out[, 1] + qnorm(1-(1-level)/2)*out[, 2])
     } else {
       newfit <- glm(object, family=gaussian(link = "identity"), subset=subset, ...)
       if (family(object)$family != 'binomial')
        out <- coef(summary(newfit))[parm, , drop=F]       
       out = lmtest::coeftest(out, vcov.=sandwich::vcovHC(out, type="HC3")) 
       val <- out[, 1]
       se <- val * out[, 2]
       out <- cbind(val, se, z <- abs(val-1)/se, pnorm(z, lower.tail = F)*2, 
                    val + qnorm((1-level)/2)*se, val + qnorm(1-(1-level)/2)*se)
     }
     colnames(out) <- c(name, 'Std. Error', 'Z-value', 'p-value', ciname)
     return(out)
   }## endif MLe code here

   

  

    Mod1 <- Mod0 <- model.matrix(object)[subset, ]
  n <- nrow(Mod0)
  Nvec <- matrix(rep(c(1/n,0,0,1/n),each=n), n*2, 2)
  
  if (method == 'delta') {
    if (scale == 'linear') {
      df <- deriv( ~y/x, c('x', 'y')) # y depends on x
    } 
    
    out <- sapply(parm, function(p) {
      Mod0[, p] <- 0
      Mod1[, p] <- 1
      Mod <- rbind(Mod0, Mod1)
      allpreds <- family(object)$linkinv(Mod %*% coef(object))
      avgpreds <- t(Nvec) %*% allpreds
      val <- f(avgpreds)
      V <- sweep(chol(vcov(object)) %*% t(Mod), allpreds*(1-allpreds), '*', MARGIN = 2) %*% Nvec
      V <- t(V) %*% V
      dxdy <- matrix(attr(eval(df, list('x'=avgpreds[1], 'y'=avgpreds[2])), 'gradient'))
      se <- sqrt(t(dxdy) %*% V %*% dxdy)
      out <- c(val, se, z <- abs({val-null}/se), 2*pnorm(abs(val/se), lower.tail=FALSE), val + qnorm(cilevel[1])*se, val + qnorm(cilevel[2])*se)
      names(out) <- c(name, 'Std. Error', 'Z-value', 'p-value', ciname)
      out
    }) # / sqrt( n )
    out <- t(out)
    rownames(out) <- names(cf)
    return(out)
  } ## endif deltaMod1 <- Mod0 <- model.matrix(object)[subset, ]
  n <- nrow(Mod0)
  Nvec <- matrix(rep(c(1/n,0,0,1/n),each=n), n*2, 2)
  
  if (method == 'delta') {
    if (scale == 'linear') {
      df <- deriv( ~y/x, c('x', 'y')) # y depends on x
    } 
    
    out <- sapply(parm, function(p) {
      Mod0[, p] <- 0
      Mod1[, p] <- 1
      Mod <- rbind(Mod0, Mod1)
      allpreds <- family(object)$linkinv(Mod %*% coef(object))
      avgpreds <- t(Nvec) %*% allpreds
      val <- f(avgpreds)
      V <- sweep(chol(vcov(object)) %*% t(Mod), allpreds*(1-allpreds), '*', MARGIN = 2) %*% Nvec
      V <- t(V) %*% V
      dxdy <- matrix(attr(eval(df, list('x'=avgpreds[1], 'y'=avgpreds[2])), 'gradient'))
      se <- sqrt(t(dxdy) %*% V %*% dxdy)
      out <- c(val, se, z <- abs({val-null}/se), 2*pnorm(abs(val/se), lower.tail=FALSE), val + qnorm(cilevel[1])*se, val + qnorm(cilevel[2])*se)
      names(out) <- c(name, 'Std. Error', 'Z-value', 'p-value', ciname)
      out
    }) # / sqrt( n )
    out <- t(out)
    rownames(out) <- names(cf)
    return(out)
  } ## endif delta code here

  
  if (method == 'bootstrap') {
    if (missing(seed))
      stop('seed must be supplied by the user when obtaining results from random number generation')
    set.seed(seed)
    out <- replicate(NREPS, {
      
      index <- sample(1:n, n, replace=T)
      Mod <- model.matrix(object)[subset, ][index, ] 
      newbeta <- glm.fit(Mod, object$y[index], family=binomial())$coef
      out <- sapply(parm, function(p) {
        Mod1 <- Mod0 <- Mod
        Mod1[, p] <- 1
        Mod0[, p] <- 0
        Mod <- rbind(Mod0, Mod1)
        newpreds <- family(object)$linkinv(Mod %*% newbeta)
        f(t(Nvec) %*% newpreds)
      })
      out
    })
    
      if (length(parm) == 1) {
      out <- c(val <- mean(out), se <- sd(out), z <- abs({val - null}/se), 2*pnorm(abs(val/se), lower.tail=FALSE),
               val + qnorm((1-level)/2)*se, val + qnorm(1-(1-level)/2)*se)
      names(out) <- c(name, 'Std. Error', 'Z-value', 'p-value', ciname)
    } else {
      out <- cbind(val <- rowMeans(out), se <- apply(out, 1, sd), z <- abs({val - null}/se), 2*pnorm(abs(val/se), lower.tail=FALSE),
                   val + qnorm(cilevel[1])*se, val + qnorm(cilevel[2])*se)
      colnames(out) <- c(name, 'Std. Error', 'Z-value', 'p-value', ciname)  
      rownames(out) <- names(cf)
    }
    
    return(out)
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/269614/3) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.